# Determine exec() time in PHP?

Tags: php, exec

How get the time for the exec() function to finish running in PHP?

In my php script, I call a linux program and I want the program to sleep for a while (as long as the executable time of the program until it's done) and after it's done, the program will run the subsequent scripts.

The `exec()` function is run in the following script. It will create a file it successfully solves the problem otherwise it returns nothing. However the program takes sometime to create the file or to return nothing. And I realized that the time for this program to return is sometimes longer that the execution of php script. That's why I need to wait for the `exec()` to finish first and then let subsequent PHP script after `exec()` to run.

```
$cmd = $dir.$programName.self::SPACE.self::OPERATOR.self::SPACE.$dir.$domainFile
                    .self::SPACE.self::FACTS.self::SPACE.$dir.$inputFile.self::SPACE
                    .self::OUTPUT.self::SPACE.$outputFile;
 $output = exec($cmd, $output, $return);

 $solvable = false;
if (!file_exists($dir.$outputFile)) {
        $solvable = false;
}else{
        $solvable = true;
}

return $solvable;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "sleep for a while"? `exec()` doesn't return until the command finishes.

Comment: You're describing the solution you created for a problem that's not very clear and is asking for help with that solution. I suggest you describe your problem better, instead.

Comment: The linux program that I call in PHP will create an output file if it's successfully solve the command passed to it otherwise it will create nothing but just closes. The problem is, the time for this program to return it result (whether to create an output file our return nothing) seems to take longer than the PHP scripts to be executed. I would like the PHP to wait until the exec() done before running the subsequent scripts after the exec() command

Comment: @PriskaAprilia The only way `exec()` will return before the program is finished is if the program forks a background process and exits before the background process is done.

Comment: In other words, your PHP script won't do nothing until `exec()` is finished.

Comment: is there anyway to check that in php ?  
I usually run the program in linux terminal but now I would like to integrate it with php

Answer (score 0):

You can use microtime as the **start** and **end** of your PHP code:

```
<?php
    $time_start = microtime(true);
    //Your Code goes here
    $time_end = microtime(true);
    $time = $time_end - $time_start;
    echo "Process Time: {$time}";
?>
```

Comment: This is not what I am asking about

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$exec_starttime = microtime(true);
$result = exec("your command");
echo "execution time:" . (microtime(true) - $exec_starttime) . " seconds";
?>
```

php will wait until your command finishes, since it needs to save the output into the `$result` variable

Comment: OP's not trying to measure execution time.

Comment: @AlanMachado title says "Determine exec() time in PHP?" tho

Comment: But the question doesn't.